# java.sql.SQLException: Can't call commit when autocommit=true in play framwwork application

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.4

My application is throwing `java.sql.SQLException: Can't call commit when autocommit=true` even I am configuring `autocommit=false` through `application.conf` file

Below is the details of my `application.conf`:

```
db.abcd.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
 db.abcd.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database_name?useSSL=false"
 db.abcd.username=root
 db.abcd.password=""

 db.abcd.autocommit=false

 db.abcd.isolation=READ_COMMITTED
 db.abcd.partitionCount=3
 db.abcd.maxConnectionsPerPartition=10
 db.abcd.minConnectionsPerPartition=5
 db.abcd.acquireIncrement=1
 db.abcd.acquireRetryAttempts=10
 db.abcd.acquireRetryDelay=5 seconds
 db.abcd.connectionTimeout=1 second
 db.abcd.idleMaxAge=10 minute
 db.abcd.idleConnectionTestPeriod=5 minutes
 db.abcd.logStatements=true
 db.abcd.maxConnectionAge=1 hour
```

Play framework version: 2.4

Java version: 1.8

Answer (score 0):

Is this thrown during application start-up and/or are you using evolution? The syntax for disabling autocommit for Evolution is as such:

```
play.evolutions.db.abcd.autocommit=false
```

Comment: no, it's coming when i tried to insert some value. And start working when i disabled autocommit through code. But i want this through conf file. I will try this option.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be something like `db.abcd.prototype.hikaricp.autoCommit=false` since Play 2.4? Though I never used it myself. But there is a difference between JDBC autocommit and Evolutions autocommit it seems (https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/SettingsJDBC#Reference).